# Pandas dataframe groupby by day and find first value that exceeds value at fixed time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a datetime indexed dataframe with several years of intraday data, in 2 minute increments. I want to group by day and include the first row that exceeds the price at 06:30:00 in each day.

```
df:

                         Price
2009-10-12 06:30:00      904
2009-10-12 06:32:00      904
2009-10-12 06:34:00      904.5
2009-10-12 06:36:00      905
2009-10-12 06:38:00      905.5
2009-10-13 06:30:00      901
2009-10-13 06:32:00      901
2009-10-13 06:34:00      901
2009-10-13 06:36:00      902
2009-10-13 06:38:00      903
```

I've tried using .groupby and .apply with a lambda function to group by day and include all rows that exceed the value at 06:30:00, but get an error.

```
onh = pd.to_datetime('6:30:00').time()
onhBreak = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x[x > x.loc[onh]])
```

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Desired output:

```
                    Price
2009-10-12 06:34:00 904.5 
2009-10-13 06:36:00 902
```

*If these rows are values in a groupby, that would be good also

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an expected output?

Comment: Returning the rows below(which are the first rows from each day that exceed the value at 06:30:00) would be sufficient. I'm not sure what a .groupby output would look like. Possibly the first timestamp of each day as the group name, and the rows below as the group values.

`
2009-10-12 06:34:00      904.5
2009-10-13 06:36:00      902
`

Answer (score 0):

Here we need `groupby` with `idxmax`

```
df = df.to_frame('value')
df['check'] = df.index.time>onh
subdf = df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.date)['check'].idxmax()]
Out[237]: 
                      value  check
2009-10-12 00:00:00   900.0  False
2020-05-29 13:08:00  3052.0   True
subdf = subdf[subdf['check']]
```

Comment: I provided a bad sample dataset, sorry about that. I've changed the data set in the question to a better example. Let me rephrase the question: Given the data set, I'd like to group by day and return the first row in each day whose value exceeds the value at 06:30:00 –

Answer (score 0):

We can do:

```
mask_date = df['Date'].dt.time.gt(pd.to_datetime('06:30:00').time())
df_filtered = df.loc[mask_date.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).idxmax()]
print(df_filtered)
```

**Output**

```
                 Date  Value
1 2009-10-12 06:32:00  904.0
6 2009-10-13 06:32:00  901.0
```

Comment: I provided a bad sample dataset, sorry about that. I've changed the data set in the question to a better example. Let me rephrase the question: Given the data set, I'd like to group by day and return the first row in each day whose value exceeds the value at 06:30:00

Comment: check now:) Note that yo could use `.ge()` instead `gt()` if you would want include '06:30' time date

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question either. I've updated the question, please re-read. I'm interested in the price that exceeds the price at 6:30. The data will start at 6:30, so we don't have to filter for times after 6:30.